# Native Push notification for iOs

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just want to ask if anyone of you know if there is a native push notification code for iOs without using third party libraries (parse, etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about Local Push Notification or Notification Through APNS Server?

Comment: If you want to send local push notifications you can scedule them form you app. Otherwise you'll need to implement the APNS server on a server somewhere. You can find more info on the apple website.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can implement push notification using APNS server. You don't need 3ld party services like as parse.

If you want to send notification more then one devices then you have to write Php/Python script and pass your device token into server and save it in database.

For more detail about push notification check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: You could write the push notification service in any language you like. As log as you are able to send the proper requests to the Apple servers.

Comment: yes i mentioned php python because they are use widely.@DaanOlislagers OP can find so many article about server script in php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going through [Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial: Part 1/2 on raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

I did not implement iOS push notifications before, but I will in the near future and this is one of first sources I am going to look into.

Please share how did it go and if you had any issues. Comments below that tutorial could be also very useful.

Thanks,
J